# No Encoder found error for a nested Java class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I've created a Scala class as follows:

```
case class MyObjectWithEventTime(value: MyObject, eventTime: Timestamp)
```

MyObject is a Java object.

I am trying to use it as follows in my Spark Structured Streaming job:

```
implicit val myObjectEncoder: Encoder[MyObject] = Encoders.bean(classOf[MyObject])

val withEventTime = mystream
 .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))
 .withColumn("eventTime", to_timestamp(col("value.timeArrived")))
 .as[MyObjectWithEventTime]
 .groupByKey(row => {... some code here
 })
 .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(updateAcrossEvents)
 .filter(col("id").isNotNull)
 .toJSON
 .writeStream
 .format("kafka")
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
 .option("topic", conf.KafkaProperties.outputTopic)
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmo/checkpointLocation")
 .outputMode("update")
 .start()
 .awaitTermination()
```

But I keep getting this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for com.xxx.MyObject
- field (class: "com.xxx.MyObject", name: "value")
- root class: "com.xxx.MyObjectWithEventTime"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to define encoder for `MyObjectWithEventTime` and use `Encoders.javaSerialization[T]` method:

```
implicit val myObjectEncoder: Encoder[MyObject] = Encoders.javaSerialization[MyObject]
implicit val myObjectWithEventEncoder: Encoder[MyObjectWithEventTime] = Encoders.javaSerialization[MyObjectWithEventTime]
```

remember, your java class `MyObject` should implements Serializable and has implemented public getters and setters for all fields.

Comment: Error:(55, 69) type arguments [com.xxx.MyObject] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
    implicit val myObjectEncoder: Encoder[MyObject] = Encoders.product[MyObject]

Comment: @DilTeam I updated answer, try to use javaSerialization

Comment: Not sure why but .as[MyObject](Encoders.kryo[MyObject]) worked!!!